# How to I see the number of sessions in the Google Analytics aquisition overview main graph?

Tags: google-analytics

Under *Acquisition --> Overview*, a graph appears around middle of the screen titled "sessions".  It is actually showing the total number of users over a particular time period, I'd like it to show the number of sessions and not users on the blue graph.

[image]

How do I change it?

Comment: I don't see where that graph is titled "sessions", it pretty clearly looks like "users" to me.   There doesn't appear to be a way to change it to sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to property settings, at the bottom the last item is the new Users setting "User Analysis
Enable Users Metric in Reporting".

Turn that off.

Answer (score -1):

In Audience -> Overview the default view is for Users, however there a pop up permits the choice to be changed to 'Sessions'.
You can save a custom report also, of course.

Comment: Acquisition --> Overview is what I am looking for, not audience overview, the very graph In the screenshot above used to show sessions but now shows users! I want to see the number of sessions there, in that graph not else where (like audience) I want to see it in Acquisition Overview!